# How to create authentication in tortoise svn

Tags: tortoisesvn

Recently I install a tortoise SVN in a server, holding the source code, and require to install it in client side, with authenication checking.

I have use apache server in the tortoise SVN server, the easiest way setup. But I meet a problem that I don't know how to create authenication checking in the tortoise SVN.

The "authenication checking" means I need to record whose is commiting which files in the SVN. Per now I can check up which files had been updated, I don't know who commit files in. I see some project source code hold by using tortoise SVN require user login to checkout the source code. I want to do this in.

So, how can set it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that, The Tortoise Subvesion is no longer to create authentication in 64 bits Windows....

The only way to do that, is to use CollabNet Subversion Edge as server.

Answer (score 0):

Setting SVN authentication up in Apache isn't very straight forward and hard to completely get solved in a single answer, but if you go to [this page of the SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html), there are pretty stright forward setup instructions to get SVN set up with authentication in Apache.